# Cordova is not recognised on command prompt. Variables have been updated

Tags: powershell, cordova, npm, command-prompt

```
C:\Users\Admin>cordova
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


    at makeError (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at windowsRelease (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:39:19)
    at osName (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
    at new Insight (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:26:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14) {
  code: 1,
  stdout: '',
  stderr: "'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\n" +
    'operable program or batch file.\r\n',
  failed: true,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption',
  timedOut: false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just having similar issues, there was a duplicate environment variable.

System variables > Path > C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

and

System variables > Path > C:\Android

Deleting the latter solved the issue. I entered the first path manually, the latter was input during an Android Studio installation.

Comment: Ahh, thank you!!
I had to change the ANDROID_HOME variable as well.
Removing the platform folder manually and re running the -

"ionic cordova platform add android"
&
"ionic cordova build android"

had it running successfully!!!

Comment: For futher issues adding the "--debug" attribute helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having similar issues. My problem was that `PowerShell` is not recognized as an internal or external command, so I added the following in the environment variable `PATH`:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just having similar issues.

So I am uninstall the node from my system and re-download the node.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30007291)